# Concatenate neighboring characters of a special character "-"

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

i am developing an application using c#.net in which i need that if a input entered by user contains the character '-'(hyphen) then i want the immediate neighbors of the hyphen(-) to be concatenated for example if a user enters

```
A-B-C then i want it to be replaced with ABC
AB-CD then i want it to be replaced like BC
ABC-D-E then i want it to be replaced like CDE
AB-CD-K then i want it to be replaced like BC and DK both separated by keyword and
```

after getting this i have to prepare my query to database.

i hope i made the problem clear but if need more clarification let me know.
Any help will be appreciated much.

Thanks,
Devjosh

Comment: regular expressions are the answer here ([A-Z])-([A-Z])

Comment: how should i make use of it in c# string manipulation functions would you elaborate more @Tom

Comment: So what do you want `ABC-D-E` to produce? `CD` and `DE`? It is confusing

Comment: @Aliostad yes you hit the problem now. why it is confusing would you mind telling

Comment: the method proposed by Kirill Polishchuk gives a good implementation of this.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but this should do the trick, or at the very least lead you in the right direction.

```
private string Prepare(string input)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == '-')
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                output.Append(chars[i - 1]);
            }
            if (++i < chars.Length)
            {
                output.Append(chars[i])
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

If you want each pair to form a separate object in an array, try the following code:

```
private string[] Prepare(string input)
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == '-')
        {
            string o = string.Empty;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                o += chars[i - 1];
            }
            if (++i < chars.Length)
            {
                o += chars[i]
            }
            output.Add(o); 
        }
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: it works somewhat close @zenxer but this is getting failed in one case 
"AB-CD-K then i want it to be replaced like BC and DK both as  different string instances" this one particularly

Comment: What do you mean by separate string instances?

Comment: Use the second method.  It will give you an array of strings.  You can then join them together however you want.  If you want to add keywords between them, you can.

Comment: @zenxer thanks for the edit and extra suggestion i can say now i will make it work using your code

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
string[] input = {
                        "A-B-C",
                        "AB-CD",
                        "ABC-D-E",
                        "AB-CD-K"
                    };

var regex = new Regex(@"\w(?=-)|(?<=-)\w", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var result = input.Select(s => string.Concat(regex.Matches(s)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)));

foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
ABC
BC
CDE
BCDK
```

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for this.

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk thanks but it is restricting the problem only to a certain set of strings i want a generic solution i can not assume what combination of characters and - the user may enter in this field

Comment: @Devjosh, What do you mean? I provided regex which can be applied to different sets of string.

Comment: @Zenexer, Are you sure? It's typical task for regexp.

Comment: Positive, Kirill.  You should avoid regexes if at all possible.  They are generally inefficient compared to the alternative manual route, which in this case, isn't all that much more code.

Comment: @kirilli oh i am sorry i did not noticed that

Comment: your answer was close @Kirill Polishchuk but i dont know LINQ much so i can not make the changes in the code anyways thanks for the efforts to help me out

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but surely all you need to do is remove the '-'?

like this:

```
"A-B-C".Replace("-","");
```

Comment: Thanks @steve but my strings are entered by user and this is not necessary that each block contain onw character only it may containg 2 or 3 or may be n number of characters like AB-C-D or ABC-D-E etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can even solve this with a one-liner (although a bit ugly):

```
String.Join(String.Empty, input.Split('-').Select(q => (q.Length == 0 ? String.Empty : (q.Length > 1 ? (q.First() + q.Last()).ToString() : q.First().ToString())))).Substring(((input[0] + input[1]).ToString().Contains('-') ? 0 : 1), input.Length - ((input[0] + input[1]).ToString().Contains('-') ? 0 : 1) - ((input[input.Length - 1] + input[input.Length - 2]).ToString().Contains('-') ? 0 : 1));
```

first it splits the string to an array on each `'-'`, then it concatenates only the first and the last character of each string (or just the only character if there's only one, and it leaves the empty string if there's nothing there), and then it concatenates the resulting enumerable to a String. Finally we strip the first and the last letter, if they are not in the needed range.

I know, it's ugly, I'm just saying that it's possible..

Probably it's way better to just use a simple

```
new Regex(@"\w(?=-)|(?<=-)\w", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

and then work with that..

**EDIT** @Kirill Polishchuk was faster.. his solution should work..

**EDIT 2**

After the Question has been updated, here's a snippet that should do the trick:

```
        string input = "A-B-C";
        string s2;
        string s3 = "";
        string s4 = "";
        var splitted = input.Split('-');
        foreach(string s in splitted) {
            if (s.Length == 0)
                s2 = String.Empty;
            else
                if (s.Length > 1)
                    s2 = (s.First() + s.Last()).ToString();
                else
                    s2 = s.First().ToString();
            s3 += s4 + s2;
            s4 = " and ";
        }
        int beginning;
        int end;
        if (input.Length > 1)
        {
            if ((input[0] + input[1]).ToString().Contains('-'))
                beginning = 0;
            else
                beginning = 1;
            if ((input[input.Length - 1] + input[input.Length - 2]).ToString().Contains('-'))
                end = 0;
            else
                end = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((input[0]).ToString().Contains('-'))
                beginning = 0;
            else
                beginning = 1;
            if ((input[input.Length - 1]).ToString().Contains('-'))
                end = 0;
            else
                end = 1;
        }
        string result = s3.Substring(beginning, s3.Length - beginning - end);
```

It's not very elegant, but it should work (not tested though..). it works nearly the same as the one-liner above...

Comment: While these methods appear elegant, they are not the most efficient.  I'd probably take the more efficient route, but it would depend on the application.  If I'm already using lots of regexes, why not add one more?